# Get samples from numpy array based in samples of another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have one matrix `a` and another vector `b`:

```py
a = np.array([[0,1,2],
              [3,4,5],
              [6,7,8]]

b = np.array([0.5,0.3,0.2])
```

Is there any shorthand function that can extract rows from `a` based in values of `b`?

For instance, get samples from `a` where `b >= 0.3` should return:

```py
[[0,1,2],
 [3,4,5]]
```

---

What i've came up with:

```py
a_idx = np.argwhere(b >= 0.3).flatten()
c = np.take(a, a_idx)
```

This works, but i'd like to know if there's a better solution (specifically to work with large arrays).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a[b >= 0.3]` is cleaner but **your method seems to be faster** (tested on 1M-entry arrays with 200 measurements and yous is ~33% faster).

Comment: I had no clue i could do that, it's brilliant. I was skeptical about performance, because i first had to get indexes, and then extract. 2 operations over large arrays.